# How to disable all labels forms in symfony 2.7

Tags: forms, symfony, label

I need to hidding all labels tokens in all forms of my project. Its posible this?
I see many answers to hide only one label from a form using form builder. But i need to hide all of labels in all forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Twig.

Define a template which overrides the `form_label` block:

```
{# app/Resources/views/form/labels.html.twig #}

{% block form_label %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then tell Twig to use this overriden template globally:

```
# app/config/config.yml

twig:
    form_themes:
        - ":form:labels.html.twig"
```

Comment: this is the recommend way but you could also decide to not overwrite the form theme globally but instead for each template with the following line: `{% form_theme form 'AppBundle:Form:labels.html.twig' %}`

Answer (score 4):

No - you really only have 3 options here:

**One-by-One**

Since v2.2 you have the option of suppressing label output on a field-by-field basis in the form builder:

```
$builder->add( 'Name', null, array( 'label' => false ) );
```

**Take a Sledgehammer to Twig**

You could overwrite the core `{% block form_label %}` to return nothing

**Hiding the Evidence**

Or, you could - via css - hide every label that dares to show its ugly face using `display: none;`

The solutions which leaves you the most room to move is the first one - but please yourself.

Comment: Not working, inside custom form type `$builder->add(SubmitType::class, [ 'label'=> false, 'attr' => [ 'title' => 'Reset', 'class'=>'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle btn-sm' ] ])`